# How to detect if an older Cadence version is still running in Production and safe to delete?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

What is the best mechanism to detect if an older Cadence version branch is still running in Production and safe to delete?  It seems like Cadence’s logger is idempotent and won’t log > 1 time, so there is no way to tell from logs/data that a workflow’s version codepath is safe to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question!

We don't have a support for this right now but I created tasks to support following 3 metrics:

- Cadence server services (history, matching, worker, frontend) versions
- Cadence client metrics (which client library the user is using)
- Workflow type version metrics (users' own workflow versions)

Hopefully soon, we will support this

Answer (score 0):

cadence server service metrics is available in our release branches and we plan on keeping this updated every time.

Cadence client metrics is available. You can specifically turn it on/off per host but note that once it's off that host cannot emit version metrics unless you restart it.

Workflow version metrics is available in the very near future (merged into master but not yet in a release branch). It will check every 10m for the domains you enable and emit the number of workflow types running a particular workflow version at that moment in time.